# Split a substring that returns from a split function

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I have a string like below

```
a_b|c_d
```

and I need to split it based on `|`.

So, the result will be:

```
a_b
c_d
```

Then, I want to split it again with `_`, then result will be:

```
a
b

c
d
```

Is it possible to do this in a single step? Like when input the corresponding string, it will return a value like following:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I have created a function for split:

```
select items from dbo.splitdetails('a_b|c_d','|')
```

It will result:

```
a_b
c_d
```

But I don't know how can I proceed the next split with these results?

Using temporary table, I hope I can do this, but I need to use this inside a function. So I think temporary table is not a good option. Cursor is also an option but when I use cursor, it will degrade the performance because I have thousands of records.

My input is:

```
a_b|c_d
```

And desired out put is:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Have you considered using a data type *designed* for holding multiple values, such as xml or tables, rather than creating this problem for yourself in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can better use Sql [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function first and then use your split function as below

```
select REPLACE('a_b|c_d','|','_')

results: a_b_c_d
```

Now use your Split function like below

```
select items from dbo.splitdetails('a_b_c_d','_')
```

EDIT:

All at a time

```
select items from dbo.splitdetails(REPLACE('a_b|c_d','|','_'),'_')
```

EDIT1:

In that case Use the Replace option in Reverse

```
select items from dbo.splitdetails(REPLACE('a_b|c_d','_','|'),'|')
```

Comment: yup will have a try .. thanks for your valid suggection

Comment: Thanks your solution is working but unfortunalty i can't use this solution because _ and | can have different meanings in my logic. so when i replace | with _ then entire logic will fails

Comment: anyway your answer gives answer to my question .so it need to be accepted.

Comment: Refer the answer again

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like this.

```
SELECT d.item,e.item from dbo.splitdetails('a_b|c_d','|') d
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitdetails(d.item,'_') e
```

Comment: sorry it shows an error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: ah, its because I look the schema name from your original question

Answer (score 2):

in sql there is a `CURSOR`

then use `fetch` to get each `SubString` from 1st select

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select items 
from bdo.splitdetails('a_b|c_d','|')

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @items

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
   select SubString
   from bdo.splitdetails(@items,'_')

   --do something on SubString--

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @items
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: when i use cursor it will degrade performance i have to split a long string based on many conditions and i need to do it with a join query so may be it has thousands of records. so when i use cursor then for each record i need to loop so it will degrade performnce

Answer (score 1):

Does this Help..

```
With value(Item) as 
(
select items from bdo.splitdetails('a_b|c_d','|')
)
Select x.Items from value a
cross apply ( 
select items from bdo.splitdetails(a.Item,'_')
) x ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function to split the string by multiple delimiters. Here is the complete function and sample output.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitdetails]
(
    @input VARCHAR(100),
    @delim VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS @table TABLE
(
    items VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @index INT;
    SET @index = PATINDEX(@delim, @input)
    WHILE @index > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @table SELECT LEFT(@input, @index - 1)
        SET @input = RIGHT(@input, LEN(@input) - @index)
        SET @index = PATINDEX(@delim, @input)
    END
    INSERT INTO @table SELECT @input
    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT items FROM dbo.splitdetails('a_b|c_d', '%[_|]%')
-- a
-- b
-- c
-- d

SELECT items FROM dbo.splitdetails('xxx|yyy', '%[_|]%')
-- xxx
-- yyy

SELECT items FROM dbo.splitdetails('xxxxxxx', '%[_|]%')
-- xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be help

```
select items from bdo.splitdetails(REPLACE('a_b|c_d','|','_'),'_')
```